# New Azure user did not get an email or link to access Azure tenant

Tags: azure

We have a prod tenant and new Dev Azure tenant
I have just added a (internal) user to our new Dev tenant but they did not get an email informing them of this.
How do I send a manual link to them to access our new Dev Tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/redemption-experience

Maybe one of those options will work for you? You can also resend the invitation main over the Azure AD Portal.